# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float' in LSTM Layer in a Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, siamese-network

Here is the Siamese LSTM neural network:

```
    first_masking_layer = Masking(mask_value=0.0)
    first_lstm_layer = LSTM(46, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.75, kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4), kernel_initializer='he_normal')
    first_bacth_norm = BatchNormalization()
    first_dropout_layer = Dropout(0.75)

    reference_input_layer = Input(shape=(23, None))
    reference_input_processed = first_masking_layer(reference_input_layer)
    reference_input_processed = first_lstm_layer(reference_input_processed)
    reference_input_processed = first_bacth_norm(reference_input_processed)
    reference_input_processed = first_dropout_layer(reference_input_processed)

    query_input_layer = Input(shape=(23, None))
    query_input_processed = first_masking_layer(query_input_layer)
    query_input_processed = first_lstm_layer(query_input_processed)
    query_input_processed = first_bacth_norm(query_input_processed)
    query_input_processed = first_dropout_layer(query_input_processed)

    concat_layer = concatenate([reference_input_processed, query_input_processed])
    masking_layer = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(concat_layer)
    lstm_layer = LSTM(23, return_sequences=False, recurrent_dropout=0.7, kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4), kernel_initializer='he_normal')(masking_layer)
    lstm_layer = BatchNormalization()(lstm_layer)
    lstm_layer = Dropout(0.75)(lstm_layer)
    prediction = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(lstm_layer)

    siamese_net = Model(inputs=[reference_input_layer, query_input_layer], outputs=prediction)
    print(siamese_net.summary())
    opt = Nadam(lr=2e-3)
    siamese_net.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
    history_of_model = siamese_net.fit([x_train_left, x_train_right], y_train, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, batch_size=64)
    siamese_net.save(model_name)
```

The model takes in two online signatures, the original and a query (original or forged), and outputs if the query signature is genuine or not. When the code is run, the following error occurs in the `reference_input_processed`:

`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'`

I assume it is due to the input shape being `(23, None)`. The data is not padded hence I have `None` in the shape.

Is there a way around this error or does the data have to be padded?

Comment: Yes, pad your data to a maximum sequence length. Also, have a look at the [tensorflow ragged tensor docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304420/how-to-encode-data-of-variable-input-length/66306305#66306305) might be of use.